# Where can I find a Perl module that calculates a p-value given an f-value and degrees of freedom?

Tags: perl, statistics, package

I am looking for a Perl package to calculate a p-value given an f-value and numerator and denominator (degrees of freedom).

I need something exactly like what is calculated in the following link:

http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=7

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Statistics::Distributions](http://p3rl.org/Statistics%3a%3aDistributions) module.

Comment: I actually use $f=Statistics::Distributions::fdistr for my calculations but I don't understand which one of these functions can help me calculate the p-value.... :(    thanks!

Comment: Statistics::Distributions::fprob is the one i am looking for :) thanks!